# registration/login before viewing

Tags: login

My website seems pre-set on forcing viewers to register/login before viewing (of any product item) is possible. And I have not been able to find a way to disable it on the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

backllem.

Check the **app/code/community** and **app/code/local** for extensions available there. One of them should be responsible for access restriction.

As Amit Bera said, it might be **WMD_LoginCheck** extension. If it is - then you can disable it in the Customer settings section (entry will be named like "Login check" or something similar).

Answer (score 0):

backllem,Magento do  `not have this type of feature default` .You need to customization this.
Need to work on magento event /observer fire a do an observer on https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-8/

Event is : `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view`

More url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340415/how-to-make-magento-webpage-avaliable-only-for-registered-users

Extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-check.html

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/b2b-forced-login.html